# Android delete database row from ListView

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, listview

I faced problem to delete database entries when i select from ListView...I got two class which is `ViewContentActivity.class` and `DBHelper.class`

In my `ViewContentActivity.class`, i extend it to `ListActivity` and add method `onListItemClick`

and i put this code,

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();        


    Cursor c = (Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    int _id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(helper.COL_ID));
    String nameList = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(helper.COL_NAMA));
    helper.deleteData(database, _id);       
    Toast.makeText(this, "Data " + nameList + " removed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

in my `DBHelper.class`, I create method to delete which like this..

```
public void deleteData(SQLiteDatabase db, int id)
{
    db.delete(TABLE_PEKERJA, COL_ID + " = " +id, null);
}
```

when i run, i got error...the error showed before i declare a Cursor

```
//Error here
Cursor c = (Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
int _id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(helper.COL_ID));
String nameList = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(helper.COL_NAMA));
helper.deleteData(database, _id);       
Toast.makeText(this, "Data " + nameList + " removed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


02-09 14:26:01.449: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):    at    com.example.untukmuna.ViewContentActivity.onListItemClick(ViewContentActivity.java:69)
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584): java.lang.ClassCastException:      java.lang.String
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.example.untukmuna.ViewContentActivity.onListItemClick(ViewContentActivity.java:69)
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3744)
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1991)
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
02-09 14:33:02.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 14:44:14.639: W/dalvikvm(15238): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40157560)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at com.example.untukmuna.ViewContentActivity.onListItemClick(ViewContentActivity.java:69)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3744)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1991)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
02-09 14:44:14.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15238):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is all my log message...i also no idea how to read it...only find any log that can be click....

how to solve this problem..??hmm

Comment: What is the error? Your log message is incomplete. If I had to guess, I would say you are trying to cast one of your list items into a Cursor object.

Comment: ok wait, i'll post the log message for you..

Comment: ok @Karakuri there is my log

Comment: are you sure each of your listitem is a cursor object?

Comment: @CChi i'm not really sure...but i also follow other tutorial..they said, by using cursor can access item in database...because what i want is the table id..in my listview, i only display one column from database only..

Comment: As I thought, you have a ClassCastException. It's happening in your onListItemClick() method, and it's where you try to cast to a Cursor. Your adapter may be using a Cursor, but the list items themselves are not Cursors. You should get the Cursor used by the adapter, move to the position that was clicked, and read the data.

Answer (score 1):

try the below code

```
db.delete(TableData.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, "Id=? AND QstnrId=? AND QstnId=?",
          new String[] { Id.toString(), QuestionnaireId, QuestionId });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your exception, I would guess that your list store string, not cursor.

instead of

```
Cursor c = (Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
int _id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(helper.COL_ID));
String nameList = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(helper.COL_NAMA));
```

try

```
String nameList = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Comment: hey @CChi i got the different way to delete in ListView...but the problem is, it always delete the first item in my ListView